# What are the ancestors of Israelites?

Tags: history

In the wiki I was not able to find who were the predecessors of Israelites.

According to

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Israelites

Israelites do not have any ancestors. Is it possible?

My question is who are the ancestors of Israelites? I would prefer sources and links together with your answer if possible.

Comment: see the book of Genesis...

Comment: See, also, that very Wikipedia article. "The eponymous biblical patriarch of the Israelites is Jacob, who wrestled with God who gave him a blessing and renamed him "Israel" because he had "striven with God and with men, and have prevailed". (Genesis 32:24-32)"

Answer (score 6):

As the Bible says, the direct line of descendants from Noach through his son Shem leads to Terach the father of Avraham who is the father of Yitzchak who is the father of Yaakov (Yisrael - Israel). His twelve sons became the progenitors of the twelve tribes of Bnei Yisrael (Sons of Israel) or Israelites who became the nation of Israel at the Exodus from Egypt and the acceptance of the Torah at Mount Sinai.

Since Noah and his three sons are the only survivors of the flood, there is no need to go further back. Of course, the direct line from Adam through his son Shes to Noach is also given in the Torah.

Since this is directly written in the Torah, there is no need to point anywhere else.